# Tab Widget in jquery - Seaside- Pharo smalltalk

Tags: jquery-ui, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

Using a Pharo Smalltalk version 1.4 image with the latest seaside version loaded, I have:

1. loaded JQDeploymentLibrary and JQUiDeploymentLibrary in my project.
2. used the sample code for the "Tab Widget" from Seaside's "javascript/jquery-ui" example.

Instead of showing the Tab widget, I am seeing some bullet text,link. Has anyone faced a similar problem? Any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely missed to add the CSS theme. Add `JQBaseTheme` or one of the many subclasses to the libraries of your application.